# How SPA sites hiding or not showing json response in devtools network

Tags: json, request

with SPA which using axios or vanilla.js with an axios, simply requests are drops into devtools' network with endpoint/json data. because there isn't redirection or refresh on the page. But when I check some of the websites that running on SPA for example "ASANA". there isn't json data return after I applied something that changes the database. also page is not refreshed or redirected, but it's **updated** dynamically.

I am curious about, is there a reason for that? For example in Asana There are lot's of tasks that user is fetching when enters the page. But in the network there is no endpoint with the json response that holds the tasks...

Comment: Please show us a screenshot of what you're seeing vs. what you think you should be seeing.

Comment: for example; in asana it's fetching bunch of projects as a list. but there is no trace of where those projects list coming from. normally there must be endpoint and json response for the list. in asana Docs, it says they are using **luna** for the front-end in-house frame like the react. I checked the source and it's not a SSR, i can't see the list data in the source code. network link of asana: https://imgur.com/3YKDyYu AND here is the my api/endpoint json data when I get a list. https://imgur.com/RWFMNd2 @Dai